# Need init.d script for Python application

Tags: python, ubuntu, init.d

I have a python based application which works like a feed aggregator and needs to be part of init.d script so that I could control the execution with start/stop/restart options. Also I want the init.d script to be setup as a cron job (I have example here).

I found one sample here http://homepage.hispeed.ch/py430/python/daemon

(PS. I don't want the script to be written in python itself).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could consider writing a Upstart task for operating systems which use Upstart.

Example:

```
# Start zeya
#

description     "Start Zeya music server"

start on startup

task
exec python /home/r00t/code-hacking/serve-music/zeya/src/zeya/zeya.py
--path=/home/r00t/Music
```

Add this to a file, say 'zeya.conf' in /etc/init

and then you can control the job using 'initctl'.  For eg:

```
initctl status zeya
initctl stop zeya
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I never heard about that
 
 Do you have any example or link for python based app? Got this link http://upstart.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Is this alternative to init.d? I will learn this and let me decide? Since I am newbie, you can suggest me. I want something easy to configure and do

Comment: Upstart is an alternative to the init daemon.

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this recently and wrote some small config files using [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/).

From the init script (pretty much barebones), I simply called supervisor-ctl with the appropriate arguments.

Also, you should note that the actual functions (eg. `start-stop-daemon`) vary from distro to distro.

Comment: Hey bangpyper, thanks for mentioning supervisord. I will look at that and upstart and supervisord.

Answer (score 0):

A counter-question really, but I've noticed, that you've mentioned cron, meaning, your app is going to be run periodically, as opposed to being run continously, in a so-called daemon fashion.

What is the sense in having commands like start, stop and restart for an application that is run periodically? I mean, your app is going to run once per hour (or something), why the need for start, stop and restart?

Anyway, since you've mentioned ubuntu, I must say, that the script you've linked doesn't comply with the current standard for initscripts neither for ubuntu nor for debian lenny. You can see the *correct* template in `/etc/init.d/skeleton`

To reiterate, why would you need an *initscript* for a *cron job*?

**EDIT**
Taking into consideration the comment, the somewhat "canonical" way to keep the application running even if it crashes or gets terminated is [inittab](http://www.netadmintools.com/html/5inittab.man.html). Of course, you can do it with a cron job as well.

Comment: It is not periodic task.. I use the cron to start the service if it is crashed :-).

Comment: well, let's be fair, it is stated nowhere in your question

Comment: it is my mistake and sorry about that. In fact, I don't know to how to restart the application if it is crashed and I found some one saying that cron is the best way to start the application if it is crashed. If you know alternativive way, i will be greatful to you.

Comment: Having a cron job poll if a job is running and restarting it is working around a bug that makes your program crash isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

> I found one sample here http://homepage.hispeed.ch/py430/python/daemon

I know is an old question but actually the example that you found is the recommended way to do that(start/stop/restart) in ubuntu and debian. And then you could do a cron job to see if your program is running.

> (PS. I don't want the script to be written in python itself).

The Script is written in shell command language.